# All predictions are close to median value when I do deep neural networks for regression

Tags: graph, deep-learning, regression, median

I used gcnn (Graph convolutional neural networks) to predict the ages of people. I applied regression on this problem, but all the predictions ages are close to the median value. For example, my age range is in 108-132, but my predictions are all close to 119 and 120. I used MSE as my cost function and I don't know why did this happen. Actually, I also change the labels into 0-1 and make regression on this, and the results are close to 0.5.....

Do anyone know maybe what happened to this problem?
Thanks